# MongoDB drop every database

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know if there're a command to drop every databases from my MongoDB?

I know if I want to drop only one datatable, I just need to type the name of the database like the code below but I dont want to have to specify it.

```
mongo DB_NAME --eval 'db.dropDatabase();'
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

you can create a javascript loop that do the job and then execute it in the mongoconsole.

```
var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in dbs){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( dbs[i] );
    print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );
    db.dropDatabase();
}
```

save it to dropall.js and then execute:

```
mongo dropall.js
```

Comment: `var mongo = db.getMongo();
mongo.getDBNames().forEach(function (dbname) {
  var db = mongo.getDB(dbname);
  db.dropDatabase();
});`

Comment: You could also just copy paste above code and type it on mongo console.

Comment: This droped my system databases (Mongo Version 2.4.3). I had to restart the mongodb process to make it work again.

Comment: I think when someone wants to drop their databases they aren't wanting to drop the mongo internal databases like admin and local.

Comment: Also, the config database, where the transactions are stored.

Comment: I just added an if condition to bypass the "admin" database. This script was very helpful.

Answer (score 125):

Try this command:

```
mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(i){db.getSiblingDB(i).dropDatabase()})'
```

Comment: Works great, and you don't have to create a js file for it. Nice.

Comment: What is the symetric to load it ?

Comment: One issue with this approach that I just found is that the db var persists through mongo console sessions so if someone was interacting with one of the databases then it would be excluded by the db.getSiblingDB call.

Comment: Nice. This is perfect for Docker :D `docker exec mongodb sh -c "mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(i){db.getSiblingDB(i).dropDatabase()})'"`

Comment: I went through the same issue and I found out this is the best solution for automation tasks. You aren't eager to write new files and download in a CI/CD pipeline so a one-liner script is very simple to manage

Answer (score 31):

You can also do this with a simple mongo command:

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach( function (d) {
    if (d.name != "local" && d.name != "admin"  && d.name != "apiomat"  && d.name != "config")
        db.getSiblingDB(d.name).dropDatabase();
 })
```

Start `mongosh` to execute this.

Comment: Instead of writing if condition for every DB, we can simple put in an array and do a indexOf.

Answer (score 19):

```js
db
  .getMongo()
  .getDBNames()
  .filter(n => !['admin','local','config'].includes(n))
  .forEach(dname =>
    db
      .getMongo()
      .getDB(dname)
      .dropDatabase()
  )
;
```

One-liner

```js
db.getMongo().getDBNames().filter(n => !['admin','local','config'].includes(n)).forEach(dname => db.getMongo().getDB(dname).dropDatabase());
```

This drops all DBs but preserves MongoDB's internal collections.

Answer (score 9):

Save this to drop_all_dbs.js:

```
var databases = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in databases){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( databases[i] );
    if(db.getName() == "admin" || db.getName() == "local"){
        print("skipping db " + db.getName())
        continue
    }
    print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );
    db.dropDatabase();
}
```

Now you can execute:

```
mongo drop_all_dbs.js
```

and all databases (except for admin and local) will be dropped.

**This answer is a copy of ALoR's one, just fix drop of system dbs**

Answer (score 8):

Adding to @ALoR's answer, for convenience you can put the following in [~/.mongorc.js](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo/#mongo)

```
function dropDatabases(){
    var mongo = db.getMongo();

    var dbNames = mongo.getDBNames();
    for (var i = 0; i < dbNames.length; i++) {
        var db = mongo.getDB( dbNames[i] );

        print( "Dropping database " + db.getName() + "..." );
        db.dropDatabase();
    }
}
```

Then at the mongo shell you can simply do

```
dropDatabases()
```

From the docs:

> Mongo will read the .mongorc.js file from the home directory of the user invoking mongo. In the file, users can define variables, customize the mongo shell prompt, or update information that they would like updated every time they launch a shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easy through c# official driver:

```
var _mongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");

var names = _mongoServer.GetDatabaseNames();
foreach (var name in names)
{
   _mongoServer.DropDatabase(name);
}
```

Comment: yes it could be an idea, but I want to do it without C#. (Oh sorry,  I used tag C# for this question)

Comment: you can create a javascript loop that do the job and then execute it in the mongoconsole.

Comment: @AndrewOrsich and @JohnSmith i've posted the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a oneliner that allows you to filter for specific names:

```js
for (const dbName of db.getMongo().getDBNames().filter(dbName => dbName.startsWith('test-'))) {console.log(dbName); const dbToDelete = db.getMongo().getDB( dbName ); dbToDelete.dropDatabase()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked best for me.

Save this to a file called `drop_most_databases.js`:

```js
const databasesToSkip = ['admin', 'local', 'config'];
db.getMongo()
  .getDBNames()
  .forEach((dbname) => {
    if (databasesToSkip.includes(dbname)) {
      print(`Skipping ${dbname}`);
    } else {
      print(`Dropping ${dbname}...`);
      db.getMongo().getDB(dbname).dropDatabase();
    }
  });
print(`Now, the only databases that remain are:`);
db.getMongo()
  .getDBNames()
  .forEach((dbname) => {
    print(dbname);
  });
```

From Terminal, run `mongo drop_most_databases.js`.

Answer (score -4):

It is as easy as

```
mongo --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
```

Or, you can start a mongo session on your terminal and write

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

Which is exactly the same.

Comment: The question is how to drop all databases, not an individual one