# mongodb - dropping a db with trailing spaces at the end

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally created a db whose name has some trailing spaces at the end (not sure how many) , and now I cannot drop that database.
When I use the shell and switch to this db without any spaces, it doesn't throw any error, but then when I use the dropDatabase() command, it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to get this done?
Thanks.

Comment: are you using `db.dropDatabase()`?

Comment: This may help [MongoDB drop every database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376436/mongodb-drop-every-database) But careful.  You can use  a regex to match the database you want to drop.

Comment: Thanks. I used the link provided above, and a regex pattern to drop the db I was interested in.